# GCP Federation/Hybrid Identity options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity, federation

What are the hybrid identity management and federation options in GCP?  For example, in Azure, there are Password Hash Synch, Pass-Through, ADFS and in AWS, AD Connector, Managed MS AD, etc. 
What are they in GCP and what are the pros/cons and requirements or best practice, etc. for each approach?

Answer (score 1):

Google has extensive documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/authenticating-corporate-users-in-a-hybrid-environment

You might want to be more specific about the nature of your hybrid cloud.  For instance, if you are using active directory, the docs are here:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/federating-gcp-with-active-directory-introduction

For a multi-cloud with Azure AD, here:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/federating-gcp-with-azure-active-directory

For LDAP, try here:
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/patterns-for-authenticating-corporate-users-in-a-hybrid-environment#exposing_an_on-premises_ldap_directory_to_gcp

If you give more details, it will enable people to help you more.

Comment: Ok.  I will read those but I was trying to have different options for different scenarios in GCP.  I am well aware of what AWS and Azure offers but very new to GCP.  Thank you.

Comment: GCP unlike Azure AD isn't loaded with features. So choose your IDP carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud supports Cloud Identity as their managed IDaaS. How to manage the hybrid identity are well documented https://cloud.google.com/solutions/patterns-for-authenticating-corporate-users-in-a-hybrid-environment

Comment: Ok.  I will look at the site.